# Memcache data update issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

I need help to optimize the rails code to update Memcache data.
The problem is like,
I have JSON data for a particular match in the following manner and writing into the cache.

```
match_data = {'teams' : 'Team one', 'Team two', 'score' { 'team1':0, 'team2': 1 }, time: 60 }
Rails.cache.write('match_123', match_data) #123 is match id
```

The above one is a very small example of a match it can have huge data.

So the match data is receiving in the application from the service frequently and updating the same in the cache and used the same to display in front-end as well.
So the actual problem is that I received the match updates in response like score, time, individually and frequently. 
So I use the following code to update the cache data.

```
data = Rails.cache.read('match_123')
data[:time] = 120
OR 
data[:score][:team1] = 1

Rails.cache.write('match_123', data)
```

I am using background jobs to perform the above process.
This process Is being too quick and we have multiple matches running together,
So at a point what is happening here as we updating complete match hash each time in the cache for a particular key-value change.
So what happening when we have two queues for example:

```
UpdateMatchCacheDataJob.perform_later(score_update)
UpdateMatchCacheDataJob.perform_later(time_update)
```

Suppose this queue runs together at a time it will either update the time in the cache or score.
This is the complexity I am facing. I have also tried to perform the job now yet got the issue sometime.

```
UpdateMatchCacheDataJob.perform_now(score_update)
UpdateMatchCacheDataJob.perform_now(time_update)
```

My problem may resolve if I play with particular data that needs to be updated instead not to update complete hash each time. Or is there a way to update the particular data in a hash

Note: I am using the AWS Memcache instance to store cache data.

I hope I could explain my issue, please let me know if anything needs from my side to explain the issue.

Comment: Why do you use background jobs to update cache?

Comment: Because we need to process and format the data first before storing data into the cache, yet I have mentioned I have also tried to use perform_now to execute Job instantly.

Comment: Can we use something like lock to check not to update the existing key cache until the existing one is processing?

Comment: If you use Sidekiq, you can make your jobs unique. https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs

Comment: Actually I analysis about the issue and found, the issue is here. Job has the following work.
`class UpdateMatchCacheDataJob
  def perform(data)
    data = Rails.cache.read('match_123')
    # Menupulate data here to update score or time.
    # write into to cache
    Rails.cache.write('match_123', data)
  end
end

UpdateMatchCacheDataJob.perform_now(score_update)
UpdateMatchCacheDataJob.perform_now(time_update)`

here, both jobs will fetch the existing cache initially and after manipulation, the latest cache will be according to the last job ran.
I hope to clear the issue now.